# How to make dragging of an Ellipse object cumulative?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am following a tutorial and have defined (in the XAML file) an `Ellipse` object positioned in the centre of the screen and which contains a `TranslateTransform` node within an `Ellipse.RenderTransform` node as follows:

```
<Ellipse
  x:Name="theEllipse"
  Fill="White"
  Width="200"
  Height="200">
  <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="theMover" />
  </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

In the code behind I have added a `ManipulationDelta` event handler to the `Ellipse` as follows:

```
public MainPage()
{
// other stuff
theEllipse.ManipulationDelta
  += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(theEllipse_ManipulationDelta);
}

void theEllipse_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
theMover.X = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X;
theMover.Y = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Y;
}
```

Thus I can press down on the `Ellipse` and drag it from its start position. I find, however, when I release the `Ellipse` and press on it for a second time, the `Ellipse` jumps and begins dragging from its initial position and not its current position. Why is this? And how would I define my dragging action to be cumulative in the sense that when I drag the Ellipse a second time, it contains from wherever it is?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have this fixed or not, but here is a solution to it:

Add event handler for manipulationStarting,and set the manipulationContainer as its mother.

```
<Window x:Class="TempProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="640"
    ManipulationStarting="window_ManipulationStarting"
      ManipulationDelta="window_ManipulationDelta"
     >
<Grid x:Name="canvas">
    <Ellipse
x:Name="theEllipse"
Fill="Black"
Width="200"
Height="200"
IsManipulationEnabled="True">
<Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="theMover" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The function should be like this:

```
private void window_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        theMover.X = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X;
        theMover.Y = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.Y;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void window_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ManipulationContainer = canvas;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

where "canvas" is the name of my grid layout containing the ellipse.